# python dataframe. Insert row based on various criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following dataframe, each row represents a part of a shift for a day.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['number'] = '169', '169', '169', '169', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713','4004',   '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004'
df['date'] ='2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023','5/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '28/02/2023',   '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '5/03/2023','2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023' ,'5/03/2023','28/02/2023',  '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023'
df['start'] = '21:00:00'    ,'21:00:00',    '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '21:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00','7:00:00' ,'7:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '14:30:00', '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','6:30:00',    '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','14:30:00','22:45:00',    '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00'
df['end'] = '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '13:45:00', '13:45:00'  ,'15:30:00',    '15:15:00', '15:15:00', '13:30:00', '23:00:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00'  ,'16:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00'
df['hours'] = '9.5', '2.5', '7', '9.5', '10', '2', '2', '3.5', '2.5', '6', '10', '2', '3', '9.5', '10', '2', '1.5', '1.5', '6.25', '6.25', '8', '1', '6.75', '6', '8', '10', '2', '3', '2', '8', '2', '1.5', '1.75', '8', '8', '8', '8', '6', '2'
df['day'] = 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday'

print(df)
```

for each row if a cell in ‘day’ column is either Friday, Saturday or Sunday AND the 'start' column is before midnight AND the 'end' column is after midnight, the row that has the balance of 'hours' that pass through midnight (lets call this row 'old row') I need to do the following.  By 'pass through midnight' an example I would refer to is number '169' starts 21:00 on Saturday; as the first row for Saturday was 2.5 hours (ie ends 23:30) it is the second row regarding Saturday for 7 hours which 'passes through midnight'.

1. insert a row (lets call this row 'new row') directly underneath 'old row'
2. 'old row' 'hours' data needs to be changed to the remaining that the entire shift for the day has to reach midnight. (e.g. for 'Aberash' out of the 7 hours only 0.5 hours is required to reach midnight (as previous row ended 23:30)
3. The new row receives the balance of 'hours' (i.e.. 7 hours - 0.5 hours = 6.5 hours)
4. The new row 'day' column data is changed to the following:

   i) If 'old row' was Friday new row is Friday/Saturday

   ii) If 'old row' was Saturday new row is Saturday/Sunday

   iii) If 'old row' was Sunday new row is Sunday/Monday

Other data not discussed in 'new row' should be same 'old row'.

Below is what the dataframe should look like after the above

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['number'] = '169', '169', '169', '169', '169', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713','4004',    '4004','4004',  '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004'
df['date'] = '2/03/2023','4/03/2023','4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023','5/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '28/02/2023',   '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '5/03/2023','2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023' ,'5/03/2023','28/02/2023',  '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023'
df['start'] = '21:00:00','21:00:00','21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '21:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00','15:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00','7:00:00' ,'7:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '14:30:00', '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','6:30:00',    '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','14:30:00','22:45:00',    '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00'
df['end'] = '7:00:00',  '7:00:00','7:00:00',    '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '13:45:00', '13:45:00'  ,'15:30:00',    '15:15:00', '15:15:00', '13:30:00', '23:00:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00'  ,'16:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00'
df['hours'] = '9.5', '2.5', '0.5', '6.5', '9.5', '10', '2', '2', '3.5', '2.5', '6', '10', '2', '3', '9.5', '9', '1', '2', '1.5', '1.5', '6.25', '6.25', '8', '1', '6.75', '6', '8', '10', '2', '3', '2', '8', '2', '1.5', '1.75', '8', '8', '8', '1.25', '6.75', '1.25', '4.75', '2'
df['day'] = 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday/Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Friday/Saturday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday/Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday/Sunday', 'Saturday'

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is ugly, slow, and generally unmanageable.
Writing it made me genuinely angry.

This is a testament to why choosing the right data structures leads to cleaner code.

Anyway, here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['number'] = '169', '169', '169', '169', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '2129', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '5645', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '7480', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713', '6713','4004',   '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004', '4004'
df['date'] ='2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023','5/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '27/02/2023',   '28/02/2023',   '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '5/03/2023',    '5/03/2023','2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '2/03/2023' ,'4/03/2023',   '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023' ,'5/03/2023','28/02/2023',  '1/03/2023',    '2/03/2023',    '3/03/2023',    '4/03/2023',    '4/03/2023'
df['start'] = '21:00:00'    ,'21:00:00',    '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '6:00:00',  '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '14:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '21:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '15:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00','7:00:00' ,'7:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '14:30:00', '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','6:30:00',    '6:30:00',  '6:30:00','14:30:00','22:45:00',    '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00', '22:45:00'
df['end'] = '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '7:00:00',  '13:45:00', '13:45:00'  ,'15:30:00',    '15:15:00', '15:15:00', '13:30:00', '23:00:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '22:30:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00', '21:00:00'  ,'16:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00','7:15:00'
df['hours'] = '9.5', '2.5', '7', '9.5', '10', '2', '2', '3.5', '2.5', '6', '10', '2', '3', '9.5', '10', '2', '1.5', '1.5', '6.25', '6.25', '8', '1', '6.75', '6', '8', '10', '2', '3', '2', '8', '2', '1.5', '1.75', '8', '8', '8', '8', '6', '2'
df['day'] = 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday'

# converting to more sensible data types
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
df['hours'] = df['hours'].astype(float)

# df_okay will be the sink for the non-problematic shifts
# any shift outside of Friday, Saturday and Sunday aren't our concern
df_okay = df[~df['day'].isin(['Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'])].copy()

df = df[df['day'].isin(['Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'])].copy()

# let's use datetime objects to compare dates and calculate durations
df['start_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + df['start'])
df['end_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + df['end'])
# let's add a day for the end datetime of shifts which go over midnight
df.loc[df['start_dt']>df['end_dt'], 'end_dt'] += timedelta(1)

# any shift which doesn't go over midnight can't be problematic
# so it goes in the sink
df_okay = pd.concat((df_okay, df[df['start_dt'].dt.date == df['end_dt'].dt.date]))

# these shifts go over midnight so they're at risk
df = df[df['start_dt'].dt.date != df['end_dt'].dt.date]

# let's calculate the total number of hours for each `number` during the shift
df_problem_shifts = df[['number', 'start_dt', 'end_dt', 'hours']].groupby(['number','start_dt', 'end_dt']).sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'hours':'total_hours'})

# let's calculate the number of available hours between the beginning of the shift and midnight
df_problem_shifts['to_midnight'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_problem_shifts['start_dt'].dt.date + timedelta(days=1)) - df_problem_shifts['start_dt'] ).dt.total_seconds()/3600

# these shifts have a sum of `hours` which is more than the available hours until midnight
df_problem_shifts = df_problem_shifts[df_problem_shifts['to_midnight'] < df_problem_shifts['total_hours']]

# simple dictionary which will be used to replace `day` with `day/day+1`
days = ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
days = {day: f"{day}/{day2}" for (day, day2) in zip(days, days[1:])}
new_rows = []
for i,row in df_problem_shifts.iterrows():
    df_hours = df.loc[(df.number == row.number) & (df.start_dt == row.start_dt) & (df.end_dt == row.end_dt)]
    available_hours = row.to_midnight
    for j,row2 in df_hours.iterrows():
        if available_hours == 0:
            df.loc[j,'day'] = days[df.loc[j, 'day']]
        else:
            available_hours -= row2.hours
            if available_hours < 0:
                df.loc[j, 'hours'] = row2.hours + available_hours
                row2.day = days[row2.day]
                row2.hours = - available_hours
                available_hours = 0
                new_rows.append(row2)
new_rows = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

# at this point df contains the shift rows for all
# shifts which had to be modified
df = pd.concat((df, new_rows))

# putting back all the shifts which were
# previously declared non-problematic
df = pd.concat((df_okay,df)).drop(['start_dt', 'end_dt'], axis=1)
df.sort_values(['number', 'date'])
```

Comment: mate, just FYI I am reviewing and will get back. Had a big weekend :)

Comment: Sorry mate for the late confirm. You did a great job. I have a follow up problem that will link here.